# Select and assign 0 for the rows which does not have any data

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.5

We have client requirement where if for a particular condition, there is no data available, then assign 0 while selecting the column from DB.

Below is the table structure. We need to pull last 6 months data from today where gender is 'M'. If for a particular month there are no 'Male'/'Female' (as per the where condition) participants, then show 0 participants for that month.

```
  yearMonth participants gender
    202101     1            F
    202102     0            M  
    202103     0            F
    202003     0            M
    202104     0            F
    202105     0            F
    202105     30           F
    202105     5            M
    202106     22           F
    202106     20           M
    202107     14           F
    202108     29           M
```

Without any where condition, query looks like below -

```
select yearMonth, sum(participants) as participants 
from table_name 
where yearMonth
between 202104 and 202108  group by yearMonth;
```

This query returns -

```
  yearMonth participants 
    202103     0
    202104     0            
    202105     35           
    202106     42           
    202107     14           
    202108     29
```

When we add a where condition like -

```
select yearMonth, sum(participants) as participants 
from table_name 
where yearMonth
between 202104 and 202108 
where gender = 'M' group by yearMonth;
```

It returns

```
  yearMonth participants           
    202105     5           
    202106     20           
    202107     14           
    202108     29
```

But the requirement is, it should also return 202103 and 202104 with 0 as participants.

```
  yearMonth participants 
    202103     0
    202104     0            
    202105     5           
    202106     20           
    202107     14           
    202108     29
```

Can we do it using Postgre SQL. Please help me if you can.

Comment: The requirement is *not* to select 0 for some rows, it's to return grouping results even for combinations with no records. This requires *creating* data even if no data exists.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, you are right. Thanks for the correcting me.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use a Calendar table and `RIGHT JOIN` with it on the `Date` column. This will generate "empty" rows for the missing dates. A Calendar table contains all dates for the next eg 10-20 years with extra columns for year, month, quarter, semester etc. This makes grouping a lot easier and faster too.

Comment: Could you please give an example.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 and 9.5 are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: You could write eg `select c.YearMonth, sum(..) from some_table right join Calendar c on c.Date=some_table.Date Where  c.YearMonth between ... GROUP BY c.YearMonth`. This will produce rows for all `YearMonth` columns with sums only for the matches in `some_table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation, which in Postgres looks like this:

```
select yearMonth,
       sum(participants) filter (where gender = 'M') as male_participants 
from table_name 
where yearMonth between 202104 and 202108 
group by yearMonth;
```

However, your condition is:

> We need to pull last 6 months data from today where gender is 'M'.

For this, I would suggest `generate_series()` so the date comparison is automatic:

```
select v.yearMonth, 
       coalesce(sum(participants), 0) as male_participants
from generate_series(0, 5, 1) gs(n) cross join lateral
     (values (to_char(date_trunc(month, current_date) - gs.n * interval '1 month', 'YYYYMM')::int)
     ) v(yearMonth) left join
     table_name t
     on t.yearMonth = v.yearMonth::int and
        t.gender = 'M'
group by v.yearMonth
order by v.yearmonth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a calendar table approach:

```sql
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT CAST('2021-01-01' AS DATE) + (n || ' month')::INTERVAL dt
    FROM generate_series(0, 11) n
)

SELECT
    TO_CHAR(d.dt, 'YYYYMM')::int AS yearMonth,
    SUM(t.participants) FILTER (WHERE t.gender = 'M') AS male_participants
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN table_name t
    ON t.yearMonth = d.yearMonth
WHERE
    TO_CHAR(d.dt, 'YYYYMM')::int BETWEEN 202101 AND 202108 AND        
GROUP BY
    TO_CHAR(d.dt, 'YYYYMM')::int;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional aggregation

```
select yearMonth, sum(case when gender = 'M' then participants else 0 end) as participants 
from table_name 
where yearMonth
between 202104 and 202108 
group by yearMonth;
```

The yearMonth raw can be missing only if there's no any participant raw in the original table for this yearMonth at all.